# Generator of the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-varieties

I know that $x^3-xz^2-y^2z=0$ is a nonsingular curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$(char $k\neq 2)$. By definition, each local ring is a regular local ring. Consider the ring of degree zero elements in a homogeneous localized ring $(k[x,y,z]/(x^3-xz^2-y^2z))_{(x,z)}$.

Therefore, this ring should be a regular local ring. But I don't know how to find the generator of the principal maximal ideal. I just know it can be $(x/y, z/y)$, and we have the relation $$z/y=(x/y)^3-(x/y)(z/y)^2.$$

Comment: Hint: what's the vector space dimension of $\mathcal{O}_p/(f)$ in relation to the valuation of $f$? Are there any natural choices of $f$ to try here? (Separately, you may want to swap to affine coordinates given by $y=1$ to make things a little easier on your eyes.)

Comment: @KReiser If I understand your hint correctly, let $f=x$, and the generator is $x$.

Comment: Yup, that's correct. Another way to this is to find an element in the quotient ring with Jacobian which is linearly independent from the Jacobian of the equation at the point in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can write $z(xz+y^2)=x^3$ in the quotient, so $(z/y)(xz/y^2+1)=(x/y)^3$ in the homogeneous localization, so that $(z/y)$ is already in the ideal generated by $(x/y)$ since $(xz/y^2+1)$ is a unit.